# nginx configuration for ssl certificate installation with rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl, nginx, passenger

I have a site that I built using ruby on rails on nginx server with passenger. My client decided to install ssl certificate.I am a newbie to that kind of issues and I have never did it before and I need to confirm that my sites-enabled/default file is configured properly.
My current configuration is :

```
server {
       listen 80;
       listen [::]:80 ipv6only=on;
       server_name www.mysite.com;
       passenger_enabled on;
       rails_env    production;
       root         /home/directory;

       # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
       error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
       location = /50x.html {
           root   html;
       }

   }
```

and for adding ssl certificate, I will add another server block like below:

```
server {
      listen 443;
      server_name www.mysite.com;
      passenger_enabled on;
      rails_env    production;
      root         /home/directory;

      ssl                  on;
      ssl_certificate      /etc/ssl/my_certificate;
      ssl_certificate_key  /etc/ssl/my_private_key;

      ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
      ssl_ciphers   "EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA:AES128-SHA:DES-CBC3-SHA:HIGH:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!MD5:!PSK:!RC4";

      ssl_prefer_server_ciphers   on;
      ssl_session_timeout  10m;
      ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m;
      ssl_stapling on



      # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
      error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
      location = /50x.html {
          root   html;
      }

  }
```

- is that a right way and parameters to configure nginx or I need to combine them in one server block ?
- is there any thing missing should I add to the previous config ?
- in the :`server_name www.mysite.com;` 
  can I replace it with my IP address instead of the domain name ?

Thanks for your time in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You can have HTTP and HTTPS servers in the same server section

  `server {
            listen 80;
            listen [::]:80 ipv6only=on;
            listen 443 ssl;
  ...
  }`
- For complete SSL related configuration I would recommend to use [Mozilla generator](https://mozilla.github.io/server-side-tls/ssl-config-generator/?hsts=no)
- Yes, but you shouldn't. Nginx will match your first server section even if you haven't set server_name properly, but such configuration is hard to support and troubleshoot

Comment: Thanks @Alex C, this actually helped me a lot specially for the Mozilla generator link and to share knowledge I added two lines for my server blocks for redirecting http requests to https:                      
       server_name example.com www.example.com;
 return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri; .                             
        I used the two server blocks as indicated.                             
        many thanks dear.